# How do I enable a clipboard manager?

Tags: 11.04, clipboard, clipboard-manager

I've manually installed clipboard managers in Ubuntu before (both [Klipper](http://userbase.kde.org/Klipper) and [Glipper](https://launchpad.net/glipper), IIRC), and found them useful.

Does 11.04 ship with a standard clipboard manager? If so, how do I enable it? If not, how do I install and enable one (I guess Glipper is the best best, given that [Unity](http://unity.ubuntu.com/) is running on GNOME)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [What Application Indicators are available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30334/list-of-application-indicators). It contains instructions on Glipper and Glippy and a few others that you might find interesting too.

To start these indicators: indicators will have an entry in the 'startup applications'. It might be set to 'off' or to 'on' depending on the indicator. If not you can add it yourself.
And some you can start from dash and have a 'preferences' to set it to start on loging in.

Comment: Sorry if I'm being thick, but how do you then add the indicator to the panel (or whatever Unity calls it)? If you know, please add it to your answer and I'll accept it. :)

Comment: @Josh Glover see the good old startup programs (most set this by themself; if it does not add it yourself)

Comment: Ah, Startup Programs... should have been the first place I looked! ;) If you update your answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @Josh Glover you sure make me work for it :-D

Comment: You are my personal Ubuntu hero to be sure, but I have to hold even heroes to the highest standard. ;)